# Merge [hellosign] => [hellosign-api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[hellosign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hellosign) wiki says

> Use to identify questions related to use of, or problems with, HelloSign's APIs.

This is the same  intended usage of [hellosign-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hellosign-api) and questions are unnecessarily split.

#### Proposal:

Synonymize [hellosign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hellosign) => [hellosign-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hellosign-api) and merge.

Comment: @JonClements what is the process to disapprove a synonym or to request a synonym removal? A meta post? (not related to this one)

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes - it'd be a meta post.

Comment: @TemaniAfif You're welcome.